# jquery.width return 0 on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using a code that looks like that:

```
img.load(function(){
    // do some stuff
    $(this).width();

});
```

In my callback the image size is always 0. It might have something to do with it but my images are locally loaded.

But in truth, if I do this.width, I will get the expected width and then I can do some kind of computation from here to change my extjs window.

After some tries, I realize that if I do $(this) all the attributes I changes don't seem to have any effect at all.

doing `$(this).width(40);` won't change the width of my image but doing `this.width = 40` will change the width of my image. It's as if doing `$(this)` was copying my HTMLImageElement within a new element and those change would be applied only if I added to the dom again to replace the old one.

I'm not so sure to understand what's going on there.

**Edit**

This is what my `img` variable contains.

```
img = $('<img>');
img.attr('src', '....image');
```

**Edit 2**

This doesn't really change the fact that jQuery doesn't handle image size for in memory images but I felt it would be good for anyone using Extjs to not repeat my error. One of the big problem in my case is that the `img` object I used was a valid object but since I'm using ExtJs, I inadvertently made a stupid mistake. I created my window that way...

```
Ext.create('Ext.Window', 
  // some settings
  items: [{
      html: img.wrap('<div>').parent().html(),
  // etc
```

In other word, the event I created was on img, but I never really added `img` to the DOM. ExtJs added html text to the DOM which created a new object which can't be modified through event and so on.

So I do have to create an id to find the new element and all of this has to be done after a call to `modalWindow.show()` is done. After that everything works perfectly.

For resizing the window, if the dimensions are set, you can set them back to `null` and do a doLayout call on the window and it will recalculate windowsize.

Comment: Can you post associated HTML? Also, you wouldn't need jQuery for this. You should be able to access the property in straight javascript.

Comment: What exactly is the value of the variable `img` in that code? How is it set, in other words?

Comment: The first parameter of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) should be URL you want to load, then the complete function. What is `img`?

Comment: @sachleen it is also an [event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) aka onload

Comment: Is the image hidden via `display: none` css?

Comment: not it isn't hidden, it's only not added to the DOM at first. I create a window and ads it dynamically. It starts loading once it's added to the dom. The onload event trigger fine but within the callback jQuery(this) doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found out that `jQuery(this).width()` does not work for images in memory. Choices are to use `this.width`/`height` or append it to the page and read it.

Comment: so i'm stuck with using this.width and this.height as I can't add it to the page again?

Comment: Yes you need to use this.width, you can use attr() if you really want to. It is not a big deal here.

Comment: I guess so, I saw a comment on jQuery.width that dates from a year ago that says the same thing. It's kind of a strange behavior. It must have something to do with layout and how is calculated dimension but still an image doesn't really depends on anything else other than itself and css

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try this...

```
 $("img").load(function(){
    // do some stuff
    $(this).width();

});
```

assuming you are using img tag only. in case if you have the id of img tag then, you should use for e.g. $("#idimg).load(fun...... contd.)